# Префаб возвращает null

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
private void Awake()
{
    bullet = Resources.Load<Bullet>("Assets/PreFab/Bullet.prefab");
}
void Update()
{
    if (bullet == null)
        Debug.Log("Fuck");
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) Shoot();
}
private void Shoot()
{
    Vector3 position = transform.position; position.y += 0.8F;
    Instantiate(bullet, position, bullet.transform.rotation);
}
```

При нажатии кнопки которая в `Unity` **Fire1**, ошибка **`NullReferenceExeption`**. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю в чём проблема. Префаб называется **`Bullet`**, точно, проверил. Если нужно будет, дам скрипт класса `Bullet`. **Unity2D**

Comment: Вам сначала нужно инстанцировать префаб, а затем у этого объекта искать компонент Bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `Resources.Load` ищет объекты внутри папки Resources. То есть в вашем коде объект ищется по пути `Resources/Assets/PreFab/Bullet.prefab`
При этом у юнити довольно специфичная работа с папкой Resources, а именно - в вашем проекте может быть сколько угодно папок с таким названием, и находиться они могут где угодно в других папках. Но при сборке проекта (или запуске в редакторе) юнити собирает все папки с именем Resources и их содержимое в один виртуальный контейнер и работать будет как будто в проекте всего одна папка с таким именем, при этом все ресурсы из этих попапок будут внутри одной виртуальной Resources.
Пример использования `Resources.Load` можно посмотреть в [документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)

А во-вторых, как вам правильно заметили в комментарии, вы сначла должны создать объект который вы ищете с помощью [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html), а только потом работать с ним

Comment: нужно папку сделать `Resources`??

Comment: создайте папку resources, положите в нее свой префаб, загрузите префаб с помощью Resources.Load, затем сделайте Instantiate  этого загруженного префаба и только после этого вы сможете с ним работать

Comment: без изменений, сделал папку resources в Assets

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdK9R.png

Comment: н та ссылка сейчас

Comment: положите свой префаб Bullet в папку Resources и загружайте его так Resources.Load<Bullet>("Bullet)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAJbw.png

Comment: После создания папки и переноса туда нужного префаба - необходимо отредактировать код. Во-первых, поменять путь к префабу на "правильный", во-вторых, переменную bullet инициализировать после создания объекта из префаба.

Comment: `bullet = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Assets/Resources/Bullet.prefab").GetComponent<Bullet>();`

Comment: вот так? Щас попробую

Comment: не работает. дальше не работает приложение вообще. Тоисть до изменений главный герой двигался а щас просто стоит на мест

Comment: ну почитайте документацию, которую я привел в ответе. или то что мы вам пишем, но внимательно. var bullet = Resources.Load("Bullet");
            var bulletObject = GameObject.Instantiate(bullet) as GameObject;
            var bulletComponent = bulletObject.GetComponent<Bullet>();

Comment: @SeeSharp, удалось разобраться?

Comment: @Александр Даниловский нет, проблема осталась